# CenterContainer makes my button too small

Tags: gui, godot

I get the perfect width for my buttons, but CenterContainer overrides that value of theirs to make the button as wide as the biggest text length of the buttons when I put the buttons inside of the container

[image: ss eg]

godot 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution is to change the text of one to add space characters before and after the text.

```
Start

    Start
```

[image]